# connection keepalive with TCP sockets in python going into infinite loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets, tcp

Background:
I am trying to accept http persistent connections with (`Connection: Keepalive`) in request header. If am correct then this could be done by setting timeout when Keepalive is received.

Problem:
I am able parse the request header and set socket timeout when Keepalive is received, But the handler goes into infinite loop as `client_connection.recv(1024)` is returning `Empty` string. Surprisingly the socket is not raising a timeout exception at all, not even after few minutes.

Sample Output:

```
$ python2.7 webServer-threaded.py
Serving HTTP on port 8081 ...
1
Thread-1 - Start Time: 2016-10-19 23:12:55.754196
receiving inside thread
Setting timeout: 10.000000
receiving inside thread
receiving inside thread
receiving inside thread
receiving inside thread
receiving inside thread
receiving inside thread
receiving inside thread
receiving inside thread
receiving inside thread
receiving inside thread
receiving inside thread
receiving inside thread
receiving inside thread
receiving inside thread
receiving inside thread
receiving inside thread
receiving inside thread
receiving inside thread
receiving inside thread
receiving inside thread
receiving inside thread
receiving inside thread
receiving inside thread
receiving inside thread
receiving inside thread
receiving inside thread
receiving inside thread
receiving inside thread
...
```

Code:

```
def handler(client_connection, threadID):
    stime = datetime.datetime.now()
    print "Thread-%d - Start Time: %s" % (threadID, str(stime))
    while True:
        try:
            print "receiving inside thread"
            request = client_connection.recv(1024)
            if request:
                client_req = request.splitlines()
                if CheckForKeepAlive(client_req):
                    print "Setting timeout: 10.0"
                    client_connection.setblocking(True)
                    client_connection.settimeout(10)
                    donotbreak=True
                else:
                    donotbreak=False
                (method, path, version) = client_req[0].split()
                http_response = GenerateHttpResponse(path)
                client_connection.sendall(http_response)
                if not donotbreak:
                    break
        except socket.timeout:
            print "inside timeout exception"
            client_connection.close()
            break
    etime = datetime.datetime.now()
    print "Thread-%d - End Time: %s" % (threadID, str(etime))
    rtime = etime - stime
    datetime.timedelta(0, 8, 562000)
    print "Thread-%d - Run Time: %s" % (threadID, str(rtime))
    client_connection.close()
    return False

def ServerMain():
    try:
        ServerIP = '127.0.0.1'
        ServerPort = int(_ENVCONFIG["ListenPort"])
        listen_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        listen_sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        listen_sock.bind((ServerIP, ServerPort))
        listen_sock.listen(50)
        print 'Serving HTTP on port %s ...' % ServerPort
        id = 1
        while True:

            client_connection, client_address = listen_sock.accept()
            print threading.activeCount()
            if threading.activeCount() == 1:
                id = 1
            t = threading.Thread(target=handler, args=(client_connection, id))
            id += 1
            t.daemon = True
            t.start()
    except ValueError as e:
        print e
        print "Error: Something went wrong!"
        sys.exit(0)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        listen_sock.close()
        sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: an empty string from `recv` means the socket was successfully closed.

Comment: @FranciscoCouzo Ah thats makes more sense, So I just break the loop if recv returns empty string

Comment: Empty string not empty for socket !